# Seeking Shuttle Orbiter Ferry Flight log

Tags: space-shuttle, history, reference-request, transport, shuttle-carrier-aircraft

Can anyone provide a link to a detailed log of shuttle orbiter ferry flights?  I'd like to know dates of all overnight stops.  I can find beginning and end dates for each ferry, but info on the stops is sketchy.

Comment: [Shuttle Ferry Flight Blog](https://blogs.nasa.gov/shuttleferry/) has overnight info and more, problem is first entry was posted on May 29, 2009. Some older SSO ferry flights are listed in [Space Shuttle Chronology](http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/sts-cron.html) starting from first test ferry flight at Dryden Flight Research Facility (DFRF) on Nov. 15, 1977 and goes to Jan. 23, 1986. I know that's  not all of them, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen those, and there is info in the Jenkins books (at least the older editions, I have not seen the latest).  None seem to have the complete story though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information can be found in a document produced by the Historic American Engineering Record as part of their effort to document the Space Transportation System.  The pdf document is located [here](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/1d.pdf) (too long to post the log).

Comment: I am pleased to be able to finally answer my question, the first one I ever asked on this site, and the reason I stumbled across this site in the first place.